# Sandbox/catch (catchall) mails sent from test environment

Tags: testing, smtp, integration-testing, hmail-server

I'd like to be able to test if my automatically sent mails are really sent, but I do not want these mails to leak to real world. Is there a way to configure my mail settings so that all mails sent from my test environment are automatically forwarded to a single mailbox?

I suppose I can configure addresses in my configuration, but if I replace every e-mail in my system with my test e-mail, I won't be able to clearly check if mails are really created correctly.

While testing, I might enter real world e-mail addresses, but I do not want to risk mails being sent to customers.

Comment: https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to safely isolate your test environment is to configure a mailserver that catches all mails from and to all domains, and puts them in one big inbox. If I configure that mailserver in my test environment, all mails are cought.

Many mailservers support this scenario. I used an open source one, hmailserver on an Azure VM. Installation steps:

1. Create an Azure VM. I used a standard DS1 v2, but a lighter version probably also suffices. I chose Windows Server 2016. Again, many others also work.
2. Give your machine a DNS name. e.g. **anymail.yourregion.cloudapp.azure.com**
3. In the portal, open ports **25, 143** and **578** for **TCP**
4. Connect through remote destop
5. On the machine itself, also open ports **25, 143** and **587** in firewall settings
6. Enable .net 3.5. I did this through Programs and Features => Turn Windows Features on and off.
7. Download hmailserver to your VM D: drive (this is temporary space). You need to add the hmailserver.com-domain to your trusted sites to download it.
8. Install it using default settings. Then configure it:
9. Create a domain **anymail**
10. On the domain tab **advanced** configure the cathchall-address: anymail@anymail
11. Create an account in your domain: **anymail@anymail** and choose an easy password.
12. Create a rule: delete all mail from
    **mailer-daemon@anymail.yourregion.cloudapp.azure.com**
13. In settings - SMTP enter **anymail.yourregion.cloudapp.azure.com** as local hostname. Set number of retries and minutes between each retry to 0. Set the remote host name to localhost port 25 (so you really cannot mail out)
14. In anti-spam whitelist **0.0.0.0** through **255.255.255.255**
15. In advanced - mirror enter **anymail@anymail**
16. In advanced - IP ranges delete localhost
17. In advanced - IP ranges double click **internet** and remove all checkboxes before 'requere SMTP authentication"
18. IN advanced - Autoban disable autoban.

Everything should work now. You  should be able to configure **anymail.yourregion.cloudapp.azure.com** in your configuration, but also in your mail program (e.g. outlook). You can check that you can send mails from any sender to any recepient. Test that mails to your regular e-mail address don't arrive in your regular mailbox.

**DIAGNOSTICS**

While tweaking settings I often looked at status -> delivery queue. This queue is not automatically refreshed, so you need to refresh it manually.
You may need to clear it while testing. (I often got into loops, resulting in many many messages.)